# Get file uploaded with Dropzone and add it to input field to process it on the server

Tags: javascript, php

I am using Dropzone:

```
jQuery(function () {

    let dropzone = jQuery("#upload-box")

    dropzone.dropzone({
        url: "/file/upload",
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        addedfile: function (file) {
            console.log(file)
        }
    })

})
```

On added file I wan't to add it to an input `<input type="file" name="file">`. I know how to create to input but don't know how to add the file, so when I submit the whole form to get it in the `$_FILES` array on the server. `#upload-box` is div, not a form and that's why I want to add every file in `<input type="file" name="file">`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. Please see this link: [Set value of type="file" via jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189953/set-value-of-type-file-via-jquery)

I think you should upload files with ajax (xhr) asynchronously as they are dropped on the div.